# When/where will the Dajjal (the anti-christ) appear, what does he look like, and what will he do?

Tags: dajjal, eschatology

I have heard lots of things about Dajjal's personality, presence, etc.  I thought it would be great to ask in this community.

- When will Dajjal appear?
- Where will he appear?
- What would he look like?
- Would he have some kind of powers?
- What will he do?

These are the questions in my mind about Dajjal.

Comment: Does that mean its a single person not a nation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assalamualaikum.
I'll try replying in brief with the use of many resources.

**When will Dajal appear?**

Although the exact time is known only to Allah, but Prophet SAW gave us some signs.

> Imaam Ahmad narrated that Jaabir ibn ‘Abd-Allaah (may Allaah be
>   pleased with him) said: “The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings
>   of Allaah be upon him) said: ‘The Dajjaal will emerge at a time when
>   religious commitment is low and knowledge has decreased… Then ‘Eesa
>   ibn Maryam will descend just before dawn and will call people, saying,
>   ‘O people, what is stopping you from coming out against this evil
>   liar?’ They will say, ‘This man is a jinn’, then they will set out.
>   When they reach ‘Eesa ibn Maryam, the time for prayer will come the
>   iqqamah will be given, and it will be said to him, ‘Go forward (to
>   lead the prayer), O Spirit of Allaah.’ He will say, ‘Let your imaam go
>   forward and lead you in prayer.’ When they have prayed fajr, they will
>   go out to meet him (the Dajjaal) and when they see the liar, he will
>   start to dissolve like salt in water. ‘Eesa will go to him and kill
>   him. Even the trees and rocks will call out, ‘O Spirit of Allaah, here
>   is a Jew!’ And none of those who followed him will be left, they will
>   all be killed.” (Hadeeth no. 14426).

**Where will he appear?**

> Anas (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: “The Messenger of Allaah
>   (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: ‘The Dajjaal will
>   emerge from among the Jews of Isfahaan, and with him will be seventy
>   thousand Jews, wearing crowns.’” (Narrated by Ahmad, no. 12865).

He will emerge from Isfahan which is Persia, modern-day Iran. However, another hadith states that he will emerge from Khurasan.

**What would he look like?**

> Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: “The Messenger of
>   Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: ‘… as for the
>   false messiah, he will be one-eyed, with a wide forehead and broad
>   upper chest, and he will be hunchbacked…’” (Narrated by Ahmad, no.
>   7564).

In another hadith, it says:

> Hudhayfah (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: “The Messenger of
>   Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: ‘The Dajjaal
>   will be one-eyed, blind or defective in his left eye, with thick hair.
>   He will have with him a paradise and a hell, but his hell will be a
>   paradise and his paradise will be a hell.’” (Narrated by Muslim, no.
>   5222).

Moreover, according to another report:

> “Written between his eyes will be ‘kaaf faa’ raa’.’” (Muslim, no.
>   5219) According to a report narrated by Hudhayfah, “This will be read
>   by every believer, literate or illiterate.” (Muslim, no. 5223).

**Would he have some kind of powers?
What will he do?**

The fitnah of the Dajjaal will be the greatest fitnah from the time Allaah created Adam until the Hour begins. This will be because of the mighty miracles that Allaah will create with him, which will dazzle people’s minds and amaze them.

> In the hadeeth of Faatimah bint Qays (may Allaah be pleased with her),
>   it says: “(He will say:), ‘I almost have permission to emerge. Then I
>   will emerge and will travel throughout the earth for forty days, and I
>   shall not leave any town without entering it, apart from Makkah and
>   Madeenah, which I will be prevented from entering because every time I
>   try to enter,  there will be an angel with an unsheathed sword in his
>   hand, preventing me from entering. On every gate there will be angels
>   defending them.’” (Narrated by Muslim, no. 5228)
>
> In the hadeeth of al-Nawwaas ibn Sam’aan about the Dajjaal, it is
>   reported that the Sahaabah said: “O Messenger of Allaah, how long will
>   he stay on the earth?” He said, “Forty days: one day like a year, one
>   day like a month, one day like a week, and the rest of the days like
>   your days.” … They said, “How fast will he travel through the earth?”
>   He said, “Like the clouds when they are driven by the wind. He will
>   come to some people and call them, and they will believe in him and
>   respond to him. Then he will command the sky to rain, and the earth to
>   bring forth vegetation, and their cattle will come back to them in the
>   evening, with their humps very high, and their udders full of milk,
>   and their flanks stretched. Then he will come to another people and
>   will call them, but they will reject him. So he will leave them and
>   they will be stricken with famine, with none of their wealth in their
>   hands. He will pass by ruins and will say, ‘Bring forth your
>   treasure!’ – and the treasure will follow him like a swarm of bees.
>   Then he will call a man who is brimming with youth, and will strike
>   him with a sword and cut him in two, then (he will put the pieces
>   apart from one another) the distance of an archer from his target.
>   Then he will call him, and the young man will come forward smiling,
>   with his face shining.” (narrated by Muslim, 5228)

For more detailed information, watch this lecture by Dr. Bilal Philips on Dajjal: Sign of the Last Hour (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gno4sufkPnE)

Sources: http://islamqa.info/en/8806