# My question is related to dajjal

Tags: dajjal

Will the muslims be safe when dajjal will come to earth? And what will be the powers of dajjal? Are there any surahs or dua that could be recited to keep one safe from dajjal? I am 14 years old and i am a beginner to getting closer to Allah SWT, and it seems as though the end times are near.

Comment: Assalamualaikum, welcome to Islam stack exchange. Your question is poorly framed as it has too many different questions in one. Please show some effort to answer the question and then SHOW us the effort so we can pick up from where you were stuck. All of the questions asked already have straight forward unambiguous answers on the internet.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn how this site works. Please search previous questions for help, as there are a number of answers about al-dajjal on here, such as [this one](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16537/when-where-will-the-dajjal-the-anti-christ-appear-what-does-he-look-like-and).

Answer (score 2):

The first 10 verses of surah Kahf!
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think learning these verses alone is not enough. One has better understand its meaning

Comment: Please do not answer the questions with images only.